# How do I configure ADB for Motorola Atrix 2

Tags: android, installation, driver, adb, motorola

I am trying to install OEM USB driver for android development.
But my device is not listed when I do adb devices on command prompt. Nor it get listed in the DDMS.
I guess my system( Windows 7 64 bit) is not detection phone(Motorola Atrix 2, ICS 4.0.4) as android phone.
When I go to device manager, I am not able to see any option such as Android Phone and Android Composite Device manager.
I did the driver installation from motorola site. Here is [driver link](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481).
I tried to install the pdanet+, it said that no android phone detected.
I am using motorola cable and using phone in MTA usb mode.

When I try to install or update drivers nevertheless from device manager, inputing the \extras\google\usb_driver\ folder, it says the driver is up to date.(Recommeded way http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)
Any ideas or suggestion how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: doesn't adb require usb debugging to be enabled? adb = android DEBUG bridge.

Comment: Forgot to mention my usb debugging mode is enabled.
Setting->Developer Option->USB debugging is checked.

Comment: try adb kill-server and adb start-server then disconnect usb cable and connect again.

Comment: Have you tried installing this? https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Comment: I already downloaded and installed.The link in the question also.

Comment: Thanks Padma for reply.But it does not work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted my mobile again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It works after I done factory/reset. I followed these instructions.

copy from [this forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1784689)

I had the same problem initially as well. I did some research and found a thread on the Moto support forum in which people with the official Razr ICS had the same problem. What finally fixed it for me was:

-Uninstall all drivers for your A2, reboot

-Install THESE drivers, reboot

-Factory reset (Settings->Privacy->Factory Reset, or something like that). Yes I know it's annoying but it's necessary.

-Once your phone reboots, just sign into google. Don't uninstall any apps or do anything like that. Don't enable USB debugging either.

-Connect for all 3 different connection modes. Wait for the drivers to download each time. If a driver fails to download, then uninstall it (not the MotoHelper), reboot your computer, enable the installation of unknown sources on your phone, then repeat this step.
-Once you have all those drivers installed, time to reinstall them with ADB!  Enable USB debugging and repeat the previous step
-Once all your drivers are installed, reboot for good measure. But you should be good to do whatever you want now.

Hope this helps. I know it's a pretty roundabout way, but it works :.